Как подключить большое кол-во светодиодов к stm32?
У меня есть несколько рядов по 8 светодиодов каждый. Моя задача состоит в том что бы управлять всем рядом сразу и подававть на него лочическую единицу или ноль(в зависимости от того хочу я включить ряд или выключить). Как можно подключить их к stm32 ? Не совсем понимаю куда должны подключаться сами светодиоды, можно ли соединить каждый ряд(8 светодиодов)одним проводом и подключить к одному порту ?

Для этого есть мультиплексоры/экспандеры

Для того, чтобы оценить возможность подключить ряд светодиодов к одному порту МК надо посмотреть какую максимальную нагрузку по току он сможет выдержать.
Типовой схемой включения является добавление ключа на биполярном или полевом транзисторе:

на месте  светодиода VD1 в вашем случае будет линейка светодиодов или любая другая их конфигурация

Да вы с ума сошли, без реле ряд светодиодов не стоит подключать.

@DiD Смотря сколько их в ряду, с ключом на полевом транзисторе с малым сопротивлением перехода - вполне себе можно даже большие количества. Или это был сарказм?

ну так то да, сарказм. Но предупредить автора всё же надо. А то сегодня у него несколько рядов светодиодов, а через месяц - 200м светодиодной ленты, намотанные на ёлку. Раз, два, три - STM гори!
